# Yes/No dialog when cancelling file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, uploadify

I am using Uploadify for file upload and want to show a Yes/No dialog when the user Cancels an upload. I tried the following, but it doesn't display a dialog. Any idea what is wrong with the code below?

```
'onCancel': function (event, ID, fileObj, data) {                   
                var x = "Are you sure you want to take this action";
                $('<div>' + x + '</div>').dialog({
                    resizable: false,
                    autoOpen: true,
                    buttons: {
                        "Yes": function () {
                            alert('action taken');
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        },
                        Cancel: function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Any suggestions/pointers would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I believe `Cancel` should be in quotes `'Cancel'`

Comment: @elclanrs why? `({Cancel:"it works"})` works well.

Comment: Have you at least included js file (possibly, jquery-ui) for `dialog`?

Comment: yes, i have included the jquery files.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var onCancel = function (event, ID, fileObj, data) {                   
            var x = "Are you sure you want to take this action";
            $('<div>' + x + '</div>').dialog({
                resizable: false,
                buttons: {
                    "Yes": function () {
                        alert('action taken');
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    "Cancel": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
         }
```

Comment: You mean the `onCancel` function is not being called?

Comment: The onCancel is being called, but nothing within it.

Comment: In the code sample the closing `}` is missing for the outer function.

Comment: I am pretty sure its not a syntax problem. The VS.NET IDE is smart enough to catch those.

Comment: @GoldenUser Which version of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

try the following for your buttons instead:

```
buttons: [{
    text: 'Yes',
    click: function() {
        alert('action taken');
        $(this).dialog("close");  
    }},{
    text: 'Cancel',
    click: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close")   
    }}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you appending your newly created `div` to the `body` of the HTML?

Try:

```
onCancel: function (event, ID, fileObj, data) {
    var x = "Are you sure you want to take this action";
    var dlg = $('<div />').attr('id', 'RUSure').text(x).dialog({
        autoOpen: true, //Make sure it opens automatically.
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function () {
                alert('action taken');
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    })
    $('body').append(dlg);
    $('#RUSure').dialog('open');
    //dlg.dialog('open'); //or this, maybe?
```

Comment: No. Why do I need to do that?

Comment: `$('<div>' + x + '</div>')` creates a new div unattached to the DOM. AFAIK, you need to have it attached to the DOM to actually display so the user can interact with it. Wrapping it in `$('body').append();` will attach it to the `body` of your HTML. You may also need to give it an `id` and call `$(id).dialog('open');` afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please tell me where I should place this code in the above function?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be necessary, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/UA5ff/1/ Maybe jQuery already attaches the dialog to the document for you.

Comment: @GoldenUser: Cleaned up answer and added example to open dialog.

Comment: @Rian Schmits: Yup, fiddle works, though I am at a loss to explain why.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="/resources/demos/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#cmdShowDialog').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var $dialog = $('<div>Dynamic Dialog with Buttons.</div>')
            .dialog
            ({
                title: 'Cancel',
                width: 300,
                height: 200,
                buttons:
                [{
                    text: "Ok",
                    click: function () {
                        $dialog.dialog('close');
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: "Cancel",
                    click: function () {
                        $dialog.dialog('close');
                    }
                }]
            });
        });
    });
</script>


 <div>
    <asp:Button ID="cmdShowDialog" runat="server" Text="Show Dialog" />
</div>
```

Try this will work for sure